# How to find the swipe direction of PageSlider while the user starts swiping the page in HarmonyOS?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I am writing a custom component in HarmonyOS using Java SDK and it is a custom page slider indicator. To do that I have added a `PageChangedListener` which provides three override methods.

```java
public class CustomPageSliderIndicator extends Component implements PageSlider.PageChangedListener{

@Override
public void onPageSliding(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

@Override
public void onPageChosen(int i) {}

@Override
public void onPageSlideStateChanged(int i) { }
}
```

Whenever the user slides a page, `onPageSliding` will be called, here I am facing the problem that the `position` and `positionOffset` are the same for sliding right and left.

So, how to know the direction of sliding?

Comment: Please check the solutions provided by experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce an instance variable (currentPosition) to keep track of the current page.

```java
    private int currentPosition;

...

    pageSlider.addPageChangedListener(new PageSlider.PageChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSliding(int itemPos, float itemPosOffset, int itemPosOffsetPixels) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageSlideStateChanged(int state) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageChosen(int position) {
                         if(currentPosition < position) {
                            // handle swipe LEFT
                        } else if(currentPosition > position){
                            // handle swipe RIGHT
                        }
                        currentPosition = position; // Update current position
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

`onPageSliding` will be called when the user slides a page, and not much to do with `PageSliderIndicator`.

The values of `position` and `positionOffset` in the `pageslider` are the same. This callback parameter is currently designed as such.

```
void onPageSliding(int itemPos, float itemPosOffset, int itemPosOffsetPixels)
```

If this parameter is set to slide left and right, the third parameter `itemPosOffsetPixels` shows the direction. Slide to the right is positive, and slide to the left is negative.

Comment: I guess itemPosOffsetPixels gives the position offset rather than the sliding direction. For example, if we start sliding to right it would be positive, at halfway if we decided to retrieve to the original position and in that process also it would be positive whereas the sliding direction would be to left.